# Find all the values of $(14-3i)^{1/3}$.

Tags: complex-numbers

I have tried to find it, but I am not understanding what I should do. Please explain in detail.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more context. What have you tried? What do you know about complex numbers?

Comment: Do you know how to write complex numbers in polar form?  Do you know how to find the three cube roots of $1$?

Comment: Yes I know how to do that.

Comment: I have even thought of using cube roots of unity property.

Comment: @somwoydipsarkar If you thought about it, why didn't you apply it?

Comment: Hint if you write $3-14i = re^{i\theta}$ with $r > 0$ and $0 \le \theta < 2\pi$ then *one* root will be $\sqrt[3]r e^{i\frac {\theta}3}$ because $(\sqrt[3]{r})^3=r$ and $3*\frac {\theta}3 = \theta$.  $\sqrt[3]{r}$ is the only positive real number that when cubed is $r$.  But there are three angles between $0$ and $2\pi$ that when tripled will be $\equiv \theta\pmod {2\pi}$.  They are $\phi_1;3\phi_1 = \theta$, $\phi_2; 3\phi_2 = \theta + 2\pi$ and $\phi_3; 3\phi_3 = \theta+4\pi$.  Or in other words.  $\phi_1=\frac \theta 3;phi_2=\frac\theta 3+\frac 23\pi; \phi_3=\frac \theta 3+\frac 43\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  if you cube $re^{i\theta}$ you get $r^3e^{3i\theta}$.  You need to go the other direction.  Remember you can wrap around by adding $2\pi$ to the angle.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the question as solving a complex polynomial equation:
$$(14-3i)^{1/3} = ? \leftrightarrow 14-3i = z^3 \leftrightarrow z^3 - (14-3i) = 0$$
Since all complex polynomials with degree $n$ have $n$ complex roots (fundamental theory of algebra), the given polynomial has to have $3$ roots (maybe some with multiplicity $\ge 1$):
$$\exists z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \Bbb{C}: \quad\begin{align} & z_1^3 - (14-3i) = 0 \\ & z_2^3 - (14-3i) = 0 \\ & z_3^3 - (14-3i) = 0 \end{align}$$
Here is the trick to find them: write up $z^3$ as:
$$z^3 = (a+bi)^3 = (a^2+2abi-b^2)(a+bi) = a^3-3ab^2+3a^2bi-b^3i$$
Substitue $z^3 = 14-3i$ and group up the right side into real and imaginary terms:
$$14-3i = (a^3-3ab^2)+(3a^2b-b^3)i$$
Since real and imaginary terms cannot mix, we get two equations:
\begin{align}14 &= a^3-3ab^2 \\
3 &= 3a^2b-b^3\end{align}
Since as I've mentioned before, we are looking for $3$ roots, this will (unfortunately) lead to a cubic equation. (However, we know that all three solutions have to be real, which helps a lot.) So solving this, we get the answers of:
$$a_1 \approx -1.35897, b_1 \approx 2.01236$$
$$a_2 \approx -1.06327, b_2 \approx -2.18308$$
$$a_3 \approx 2.42224, b_3 \approx 0.170721i$$
So our three complex solutions are:
$$(14-3i)^{1/3} \approx \begin{align} & -1.35897 + 2.01236i, \\ & -1.06327 -2.18308i,& \\ & \quad 2.42224 + 0.170721i.\end{align}$$
Try raising any of these solutions to the $3$rd power! You'll get (approximately) $14-3i$.

Answer (score 0):

we can let:
$$z_0=14-3i$$
this can be represented in polar coordinates as follows:
$$r=\sqrt{14^2+3^2}=\sqrt{205}$$
$$\theta=-\arctan\left(\frac{3}{14}\right)\approx-0.211$$
$$\therefore z_0=\sqrt{205}e^{-0.211i}$$
When we take roots of a complex number they will be equally spaced in a circle, with the same $r_i$ but a different $\theta_i$. These roots can be expressed as:
$$\left(\sqrt{205}e^{-0.211i}\right)^{1/3}=205^{1/6}e^{\frac{-0.211}{3}+\frac{2\pi n}{3}}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,n=[0,1,2]$$
so we can say our three roots are:
$$z_1=205^{1/6}\exp\left(-\frac{0.211}{3}\right)$$
$$z_2=205^{1/6}\exp\left(-\frac{0.211}{3}+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)$$
$$z_3=205^{1/6}\exp\left(-\frac{0.211}{3}+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)$$
Now you can work out the exact values if you need using:
$$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$